# Why would Hadoop hftp serve directories but not files?

Tags: hadoop, filesystems

I'm trying to move files from one cluster to another using distcp, using the hftp protocol as specified in their instructions.

I can read directories over hftp, but when I attempt to get a file I get a 500 (internal server error). To eliminate the possibility of network and firewall issues, I'm using hadoop fs -ls and hadoop fs -cat commands on the source server in order to attempt to figure out this issue.

This provides a directory of the files:

```
hadoop fs -ls logfiles/day_id=19991231/hour_id=1999123123
-rw-r--r--   3 username supergroup        812 2012-12-16 17:21 logfiles/day_id=19991231/hour_id=1999123123/000008_0
```

This gives me a "file not found" error, which it should because the file isn't there:

```
hadoop fs -cat hftp://hserver.domain.com:50070/user/username/logfiles/day_id=19991231/hour_id=1999123123/000008_0x
cat: `hftp://hserver.domain.com:50070/user/username/logfiles/day_id=19991231/hour_id=1999123123/000008_0x': No such file or directory
```

This line gives me a 500 internal server error. The file is confirmed on the server.

```
hadoop fs -cat hftp://hserver.domain.com:50070/user/username/logfiles/day_id=19991231/hour_id=1999123123/000008_0
cat: HTTP_OK expected, received 500
```

Here is a stack trace of what distcp logs when I attempt this:

```
java.io.IOException: HTTP_OK expected, received 500
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HftpFileSystem$RangeHeaderUrlOpener.connect(HftpFileSystem.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ByteRangeInputStream.openInputStream(ByteRangeInputStream.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ByteRangeInputStream.getInputStream(ByteRangeInputStream.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ByteRangeInputStream.read(ByteRangeInputStream.java:187)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.copy(DistCp.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:547)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

Can someone tell me why hftp is failing to serve files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and eventually found a solution.

Everythning is explained here in details: http://www.swiss-scalability.com/2015/01/hadoop-hftp-returns-error-httpok.html

But in a nutshell, we're probably binding the NameNode RPC on a wildcard address (i.e. dfs.namenode.rpc-address point to the IP of the interface, and not 0.0.0.0).

Does not work with HFTP:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:8020</value>
</property>
```

Works with HFTP:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
    <value>10.0.1.2:8020</value>
</property>
```